# hasErrors with indexed property

Tags: grails, groovy

I am having hard time getting hasErrors to work with indexed properties. For example

```
class Order {
  String prop1
  String prop2

  static hasMany = [items: Item]
}

class Item {
  String name

  static constraints = {
    name(blank:false)
  }
}
```

Validation works properly and on item.name being blank I do get an error with

```
<g:renderErrors bean="${orderInstance}"/>
```

However, I am trying to have input box highlighted using hasErrors :

```
<g:each in="${orderIntsance.items}" status="i" var="item">
  <span class="field ${hasErrors(bean: orderInstance, field: ????????? , 'errors')}">
    <g:textField name="items[${i}].name" value="${item?.name}"/>
  </span>
</g:each>
```

Not sure how to get to it with a field: property, any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: doing ${hasErrors(bean: orderInstance, field: 'item.name', 'errors') works but that is not indexed

Comment: Docs might help: http://www.grails.org/doc/1.2.2/guide/single.html#7.3%20Validation%20on%20the%20Client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, got to implement a custom validator per Grails Validation doc page (duh):

"In some situations (unusual situations), you might need to know how to transfer an error from a nested child object to a parent domain object. In some circumstances, if you validate the children objects before the parent object, then the errors on the children objects will get reset before the object is sent to the JSP." (http://www.grails.org/Validation)

```
static constraints = {
  children( nullable:true, validator: {val, obj, errors ->
    def errorFound = false;
    val.each{ child ->
      if(!child .validate()){
        errorFound = true;
        child .errors.allErrors.each{ error->
          obj.errors.rejectValue('children', "parent.child.invalid",
            [child, error.getField(), error.getRejectedValue()] as Object[],
            "For source [${child}], 
              field [${error.getField()}] with value [${error.getRejectedValue()}] is invalid.")
        }
      }
    }
    if(errorFound) return false;
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement and tried the following way and it worked. Just wanted to share it

```
${hasErrors(bean: orderInstance, field: 'items['+ i +'].name', 'errors')
```

Comment: Thanks demongolem for adding extra spaces to my answer... :)